# Undo paste in vim

Tags: vim

I know about `u` and `Ctrl-r` for undo and redo. But `u` takes me back to the last saved state. I want to know how to undo a paste `cmd-v`.

For example,

```
I am typing here bla bla bla, [link to website](here I paste a wrong http link 
with cmd-v)
```

Then I want to go back to,

```
I am typing here bla bla bla, [link to website](
```

Is there any way I can do it in vim?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm wholly ignorant of how Apple keyboards with cmd rather than ctrl interact with vim, so you may need to change or fine-tune some of this.

The correct way to paste in vim is to use the `p` command. To paste from the system clipboard, you would use `"*p`. So, the standard way of doing things would be to leave insert mode and `"*pa` (the `a`, of course, re-enters insert mode).

If you want to have a keyboard shortcut to use within insert mode, it would seem natural to do something like:

```
inoremap <c-v> <esc>"*pa
```

(That is: actually type what is there rather than pressing ctrl+v and escape).

At first glance it would seem like this *should* provide the behaviour you want -- it's just automating the standard pasting process I described above. But it does not. Vim treats all parts of a command as part of the same undo block, and to vim insert mode itself is a sort of command.

However, you can manually start a new undo block while in insert mode by using ctrl+g followed by `u` (yes, I know, this key chording seems fairly un-vim-like, but there you go). So, you can amend the key remapping like so:

```
inoremap <c-v> <c-g>u<esc>"*pa
```

All of this will work with ctrl+v (I've just tested it on Windows and it works there, at least), you may need to use something different (other than `<c-v>`) for cmd-based shortcuts within vim.  If you're using an Apple keyboard, that implies OSX -- if cmd+v is a system shortcut, I'm not sure what would take priority. Some superficial googling suggests you may need to fiddle with some OS-level configuration to get cmd working properly with vim.

Answer (score 0):

In MacVim, you need to unmap the `Edit > Paste` menu item in order to override the shortcut, then you can remap Cmd-V (`D-v` in MacVim parlance) to the appropriate command in each mode. I added this to my `~/.gvimrc` and now everything works wonderfully:

```
macmenu Edit.Paste key=<nop>
noremap <D-v> "*P
cnoremap <D-v> <C-r><C-o>*
inoremap <D-v> <C-g>u<C-r><C-o>*
```

The `<C-g>u` is necessary only in insert mode to fix the undo history; the `noremap` and `cnoremap` are simply to restore the default paste behavior in the normal and command modes.

Thanks to evilsoup for pointing me in the right direction here.